# SQL Remove duplicate within column and second column - A,B & B,A

Tags: sql

Table

```
Column1  | Column2 
-------------------
     A   |  B
     B   |  A
```

I want to remove the second pair of B, A

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: If you have two rows with (C,C), do you want to keep one and delete one?

Comment: [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1):

This query uses standard SQL:

```
select distinct t.column1, t.column2 
from tablename t
where t.column1 <= t.column2
or not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where column1 = t.column2 and column2 = t.column1
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3TbSrdTztd2SAv6ASSqcEG/1).

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMS supports least() and greatest() functions. If yours does, you can use:

```
select distinct least(col1, col2) as col1, greatest(col1, col2)
from the_table;
```

Comment: This would return a row like `C,D` even when there is only `D,C` in the table and not `C,D`.

Comment: And if the DB doesn't support `LEAST/GREATEST`, consider `CASE WHEN Column1 < Column 2 THEN Column1 Else Column2 END as Column1, CASE WHEN Column1 < Column 2 THEN Column2 Else Column1 END as Column2 `

Answer (score 0):

```
with data(c1, c2) as (
    select a, b from T union
    select b, a from T
), rnk as (
    select c1, c2,
        row_number() over (
            partition by c1, c2, abs(c1 - c2)
            order by sign(c1 - c2)) as rn
    from data
select c1, c2 from rnk where rn = 1;
```

This approach might be extendable otherwise it's just academic at this point. Not sure if you'd realistically want to do six permutations of three columns or 24 permutations of four columns, etc. or that it's a good idea.

Comment: I'm not sure this works.. A,B and B,A after the union will become A,B and B,A and A,B and B,A but distincting them just returns us to the original resultset. If anything this then makes things worse because it turns a sole C,D into C,D and D,C

Comment: Will not return the row (D,C), even if there's no (C,D),

Comment: @jarlh, I was just thinking about that.

Answer (score 0):

The left-anti-join way of doing it:

```
select t.* 
from tablename t
left join tablename t2
on t.Column1 = t2.Column2 and 
   t.Column2 = t2.Column1 and
   t.Column1 > t.Column2
where t2.Column1 is null
```